# Winter is here, what measures should be taken to protect a motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, winter

After a mere two months of owning a motorcycle, it's already winter and I'd like to know how best to prepare for the inevitable ice/snow/cold.  Other than basic cleaning and lubrication, are any other parts at risk?

Due to my inexperience I may decide to put the bike in storage if conditions get too poor, should I do anything before/after storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any exposed metal will be prone to oxidisation, especially if the people in charge of roads salt them in winter. ACF50 after a good wash should help protect it. Other products from wd40 and scottoiler are available but ACF50 seems to get the best reviews.

Rinse the bike down after a wet ride or after riding on freshly salted roads.

If your bike has a plastic tank drain it before laying it up, if its steel, it may be better to fill it right up to inhibit rusting.

I would also put it up on front and rear paddock stands to stop the tyres deforming and then hook up a battery tender to keep the battery in good shape.

Finally i take the opportunity each winter to do an oil and brake/clutch fluid change.